# Vue.js - handling metadata with vue-simple-headful

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I use **vue-simple-headful** plugin to work with metadata in vue.js app , page title, description, keywords, etc...

I have the following setup in my vue app:

**main.js**

```
import vueHeadful from 'vue-simple-headful';
Vue.use(vueHeadful, {component: true});
```

**component's function:**

```
headful(vm) {
    return {
        title: this.category.header,
        description: 'yay, a static description'
    }
```

The page title is updated from ***this.category.header***, but only once, during the first call to the component. Following calls to the component with the **headful** function do not update the page title.

I would like it to be dynamic, that is whenever component's function is called page title and other metadata is updated accordingly.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum viable example of your issue? I cannot replicate the issue with the code you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using **vue-headful** instead of **vue-simple-headful**. Following the example from [How to set the Document  with Vue.js](https://silvantroxler.ch/2018/set-document-title-with-vuejs/) has done the trick.